# Is there an equivalent of "newwindow" for bing?

Tags: javascript, search-engine

There is an url argument #newwindow for google like this:

```
aOpenLink1.href = "https://www.google.com/#newwindow=1&safe=strict&q=" + searchString;
```

With this url, you can open a new browser tab when you click on the result link. I tried this for `global.bing.com`, but failed.

[image]

I know, there is an option in bing settings, but I can't ask every user to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `window.open()` in Javascript:

```
window.open('https://bing.com', '_blank');
```

See: [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

To open a new window on every call of `window.open()`, use the special value `_blank` for windowName.

Comment: Sorry I didn't state it clear. I don't want to popup bing website .... for example, https://global.bing.com/search?q=test
On the search result page, I want to open the target websites in new tabs.The result page, I can't modify it, it's not under my control.